# How do I call upon ALL the elements of my array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.5

I am trying to get my code to identify everything in my array however what I thought you should do is not working...Any suggestions???

Here is my code:

```
version = ['4','4s','5','5C','5S','6','6 Plus','6+','6S','6S', Plus','6S+','SE','7','7 Plus','7+']

if make == version[0-14]:
    print (m
```

Comment: You seem to miss putting quotation marks ever so often, `make` is not defined, you're using wrong syntax for slice notation (you should use `version[0:14]`) and your print statement is incomplete. Make sure to proofread your question before posting and look up a beginner tutorial since all of them will go over this exact question pretty early on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is see if `make` is in your list. The way you do this in Python is with the `in` operator:

```
version = ['4','4s','5','5C','5S','6','6 Plus','6+','6S','6S', 'Plus','6S+','SE','7','7 Plus','7+']

if make in version:
    print (make)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
m = '4'
if any([m == v for v in version[0:14]]):
    print(m)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish from your sample. Are you just trying to see if the value of `make` exists in the `version` list? If so, change this:

```
if make == version[0-14]:
```

to this:

```
if make in version:
```

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear enough...thank you for the help though

Answer (score 0):

There is missing a ' in front of the second "Plus"

```
version = ['4','4s','5','5C','5S','6','6 Plus','6+','6S','6S', 'Plus','6S+','SE','7','7 Plus','7+']

if make == version[0-14]:
    print (m
```